# SSRS Create Subscription via C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to create subscriptions for reports via C# code using Web Reference CreateSubscription method. I have tried:

- Using Web Reference and Service Reference. Both give error that is below.
- Connecting to 2 different SSRS servers (localbox and on another server on the network)
- On the local machine I tweaked permission of the user account to have admin level access.
- Tried different parameters in web.config from examples on internet

The error that I get is:

> "**System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The report server
>   cannot open a connection to the report server database**".

I am a bit stuck at this point. I am not sure if the SSRS is not configured correctly or I need to pass in a certain credentials via C# when I make the call. Any ideas?

Resources Used:

- https://ssrstutorials.blogspot.com/2012/10/lesson-12-using-ssrs-web-services.html
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.createsubscription.aspx
- https://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2012/05/accessing-report-server-using-report.html

Web Reference URL:

- http://localhost:80/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx

Code:

```
         ReportingService2005 rs = new ReportingService2005();
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        string report = "/Demo/DemoReport";
        string desc = "Send email";
        string eventType = "TimedSubscription";
        string scheduleXml = @"<ScheduleDefinition><StartDateTime>2017-11-
        24T09:00:00-08:00</StartDateTime><WeeklyRecurrence>
        <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval><DaysOfWeek><Monday>True</Monday>
        </DaysOfWeek></WeeklyRecurrence></ScheduleDefinition>";

        ParameterValue[] extensionParams = new ParameterValue[8];

        extensionParams[0] = new ParameterValue();
        extensionParams[0].Name = "TO";
        extensionParams[0].Value = "demo@demo.com";

        extensionParams[1] = new ParameterValue();
        extensionParams[1].Name = "ReplyTo";
        extensionParams[1].Value = "demo@demo.com";

        extensionParams[2] = new ParameterValue();
        extensionParams[2].Name = "IncludeReport";
        extensionParams[2].Value = "True";

        extensionParams[3] = new ParameterValue();
        extensionParams[3].Name = "RenderFormat";
        extensionParams[3].Value = "MHTML";

        extensionParams[4] = new ParameterValue();
        extensionParams[4].Name = "Subject";
        extensionParams[4].Value = "@ReportName was executed at 
        @ExecutionTime";

        extensionParams[5] = new ParameterValue();
        extensionParams[5].Name = "Comment";
        extensionParams[5].Value = "Demo";

        extensionParams[6] = new ParameterValue();
        extensionParams[6].Name = "IncludeLink";
        extensionParams[6].Value = "True";

        extensionParams[7] = new ParameterValue();
        extensionParams[7].Name = "Priority";
        extensionParams[7].Value = "NORMAL";

        ParameterValue parameter = new ParameterValue();
        parameter.Name = "";
        parameter.Value = "";

        ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[1];
        parameters[0] = parameter;

        string matchData = scheduleXml;
        ExtensionSettings extSettings = new ExtensionSettings();
        extSettings.ParameterValues = extensionParams;
        extSettings.Extension = "Report Server Email";

        try
        {
            rs.CreateSubscription(report, extSettings, desc, eventType, 
            matchData, parameters);
        }

        catch (SoapException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Detail.InnerXml.ToString());
        }
```

Error:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The report server cannot
>   open a connection to the report server database. A connection to the
>   database is required for all requests and processing. --->
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportServerDatabaseUnavailableException:
>   The report server cannot open a connection to the report server
>   database. A connection to the database is required for all requests
>   and processing.   at
>   Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.Global.EnsureModeFromCatalog()
>   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.Global.EnsureRSNativeMode()
>   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2005..ctor()

Comment: I see that you are new'ing up a reporting service object (`ReportingService2005`), but I don't see where you are setting its Url property with the value it should use to connect the that actual service. Are you doing that somewhere else?

Comment: So the error you are seeing happens when your Report Server is unable to communicate to its Report Server database. Can you check if you are able to connect to your Report Server without any issues?

Comment: Adding the URL property did make the code work using Web Reference. Thanks.